# Blank screen trying to boot from CD for install

Tags: boot, grub2, cd

I am pretty convinced as to why LINUX flavors will never be mainstream for general consumers.  It is because of problems like I am encountering.

I download and the installer ISO and made the CD to install UBUNTU.  I used it to install on 1 machine just fine.
I try to use the same CD to boot another machine in order to install Ubuntu and it does not boot.  The CD spins, there is some disk activity, the cursor flashes for a bit in the upper left and that's where it ends.  Blank screen and nothing else happens ... forever until I reboot.

All of the searching I do in Google and in these forums don't result in any comprehensive... useful information.  I am not a geek, so I don't want to type a bunch of commands to get around this.  I would be happy with a simple explanation if someone could be so kind.  This is so frustrating.  End Rant.

By the way, I looked around in BIOS and such for Legacy Mode, tried Xubuntu and some other thingsI found on the forums.... all fail to get past this blank screen.  I can only hit Esc when I see what I believe is the GRUB splash and I get to select the Language.  But after that is only the small disk activity then blank screen forever.

Comment: is it an Acer laptop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

After you boot up and the screen is black for some time press CTRL + ALT + F2 and **blindly** type the following command and then press ENTER:

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
```

To get back to your graphical xsession, press CTRL + ALT + F7.

If this fixes your problem, you may need to do the following after installation.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Edit these two lines

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to read as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

and then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

sources

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1742352

and

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2118083

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply _mchid_ .
Although your suggested commands didn't work, I was able to get past the blank screen by selecting _nomodeset_ after pressing Esc at the Grub splash and then F6 for Options.

I am stuck now further in the process at the screen for selecting the disk allocations. My Continue button is gray no matter which direction I slide the disk space selector.  

I suspect I do not have enough disk space, even though there is 8GB free on the drive and I am installing **_XUbuntu_**.

Thanks again.

Comment: @mmediaman you can select "NO_MODESET" by pressing, I believe it's, F6 when you get to the screen just after you select the Language and just before you select the option to install now or "try ubuntu without installing" towards the bottom there is a selection for "more options" again, I think it's F6 but may be different F button and a list of options is given; nomodeset is like the first one .

Comment: yes what you describe is exactly what I did. However once the install process is under way, I get stuck at the screen for designating partition space.  The Continue button is gray no matter how I size the partition.

I'm beginning to believe the machine is just not compatible for any flavor of Ubuntu.  The available partition space as mentioned should be more than enough for XUbuntu.